# Powershell -like, -gt, etc

Tags: powershell

I just started learning Powershell. Can somebody please explain to me or give me the exact name for these: -gt, -like, etc. I just tried to Google them but can't find the proper link for explanation.

Thank you very much!

Comment: They're called operators, see `Get-Help about_Comparison_Operators`

Comment: Google excludes the words that start with a minus symbol so simply delete it.

Answer (score 2):

These are called comparsion operators.

`-gt`

> Greater than.

Example:

```
PS C:\> 8 -gt 6
True

PS C:\> 7, 8, 9 -gt 8
9
```

`-Like`

> Match using the wildcard character (*).

Example:

```
PS C:\> "Windows PowerShell" -like "*shell"
True

PS C:\> "Windows PowerShell", "Server" -like "*shell"
Windows PowerShell
```

A Google search for `Powershell comparison operators` finds the Powershell documentation page:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx

> Windows PowerShell includes the following comparison operators:

```
-eq
-ne
-gt
-ge
-lt
-le
-Like
-NotLike
-Match
-NotMatch
-Contains
-NotContains
-In
-NotIn
-Replace
```

> By default, all comparison operators are case-insensitive. To make a 
>      comparison operator case-sensitive, precede the operator name with a "c".
>      For example, the case-sensitive version of "-eq" is "-ceq". To make the
>      case-insensitivity explicit, precede the operator with an "i". For example,
>      the explicitly case-insensitive version of "-eq" is "-ieq".